# ESLint: how to spaced-comment exceptions on VSCode folding regions comments

Tags: eslint

I have `spaced-comment` in my configuration for `ESLint` to enforce spacing in comments but cannot determine how to add VSCode's [folding regions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_folding-regions) comments to the `exceptions` array.

ESLint config:

```
"spaced-comment": [ "error", "always", {
    "line": {
        "exceptions": ["#region", "#endregion", "region", "endregion"]
    }
}]
```

Source code

```
//#region My region
//#endregion My region
or
//region My region
//endregion My region
```

Message from ESLint:

```
Expected exception block, space or tab after '//' in comment.
```

Expectation: ESLint should allow me to use commented VSCode folding regions without forcing me to add a space between `//` and `#region`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this by using `markers` instead of `exceptions`:

```
"spaced-comment": [ "error", "always", {
    "line": {
        "markers": ["#region", "#endregion", "region", "endregion"]
    }
}]
```