# Is there a common region comment for both VS Code and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, ide, webstorm

In VS Code we have to use following syntax to section out a region:

```js
// #region 
content relevant to this region
// #endregion
```

But for IntelliJ it's as follows:

```js
// region
content relevant to this region
// endregion
```

(Above code snippets are from JavaScript)

**Anyone knows a common pattern to use which will support in both IDEs ?**

Comment: any programming language in particular that you want this for? Or for all languages? Ex. for JS/TS, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29379

Comment: @starball Thanks for the link and using //#region //#endregion it will support both VSCode and IntelliJ IDEA but now eslint is complaining about the 'spaced-comment' violation

Comment: why'd you tag [tag:webstorm] if your question is about IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `//#region` and `//#endregion` work for both? Not sure if that applies to all languages. I assume you're working with JS/TS?

If that ends up giving you lint warnings for some linter, that might be solvable. Ex. For ESLint, see [ESLint: how to spaced-comment exceptions on VSCode folding regions comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62469552/11107541).

As for finding out what region folding comments work in VS Code, that can depend on what language support extensions you are using, and what exactly they implement. [VS Code comes with some builtin](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding), but language extensions can add their own (see [`FoldingRangeProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FoldingRangeProvider)).